# Aldebaran Nao robot simulator without a real robot

Tags: visual-studio-2010, simulator, nao-robot, choregraphe

I want to get the hang of developing on the Nao robot but without having the actual robot yet (I will get it later). So I installed the software at home but I cannot see any robot at the Robot View of Choregraphe.

Just installed Choregraphe Suite 2.1.0.19-vs2010 and also Downloaded and Extracted naoqi sdk 2.1.0.19-vs2010.

I followed the instructions:

- Choregraphe started
- naoqi also started via cmd
- naoqi attached to Choregraphe

But still no virtual robot to be seen at my Robot View tab in Choregraph.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to use the Virtual Robot.

In choregraphe menu, click the Connection/Connect to Virtual Robot

Comment: thanks! I found the solution.
Should have never downloaded the naoqi sdk.
Choregraphe Suite already had a Simulator.